# Creating threads from within a Python multiprocess

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm writing code for a game, with the AI running as threads. They are stored in a list with the relevant information so that when their character 'dies', they can be efficiently removed from play by simply removing them from the list of active AIs.

The threads controlling them were initially called from within another thread while a tkinter window controlling the player runs in the main thread - however, the AI threads caused the main thread to slow down. After searching for a way to decrease the priority of the thread creating the AI, I found that I would have to use multiprocessing.Process instead of threading.Thread, and then altering its niceness - but when I try to do this, the AI threads don't work. The functions running this are defined within `class AI()`:

```
def start():
    '''
    Creates a process to oversee all AI functions
    '''
    global activeAI, AIsentinel, done
    AIsentinel=multiprocessing.Process(target=AI.tick,args=(activeAI, done))
    AIsentinel.start()
```

and

```
def tick(activeAI, done):
    '''
    Calls all active AI functions as threads
    '''
    AIthreads=[]
    for i in activeAI:
        # i[0] is the AI function, i[1] is the character class instance (user defined)
        # and the other list items are its parameters.
        AIthreads.append(threading.Thread(name=i[1].name,target=lambda: i[0](i[1],i[2],i[3],i[4],i[5])))
        AIthreads[-1].start()
    while not done:
        for x in AIthreads:
            if not x.is_alive():
                x.join()
                AIthreads.remove(x)
                for i in activeAI:
                    if i[1].name==x.name:
                        AIthreads.append(threading.Thread(name=i[1].name,target=lambda: i[0](i[1],i[2],i[3],i[4],i[5])))
                        AIthreads[-1].start()
```

The outputs of these threads should display in stdout, but when running the program, nothing appears - I assume it's because the threads don't start, but I can't tell if it's just because their output isn't displaying. I'd like a way to get this solution working, but I suspect this solution is far too ugly and not worth fixing, or simply cannot be fixed.

In the event this is as horrible as I fear, I'm also open to new approaches to the problem entirely.

I'm running this on a Windows 10 machine. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

The actual print statement is within another thread - when an AI performs an action, it adds a string describing its action to a queue, which is printed out by yet another thread (as if I didn't have enough of those). As an example:

```
battle_log.append('{0} dealt {1} damage to {2}!'.format(self.name,damage[0],target.name))
```

Which is read out by:

```
def battlereport():
    '''
    Displays battle updates.
    '''
    global battle_log, done
    print('\n')
    while not done:
        for i in battle_log:
            print(i)
            battle_log.remove(i)
```

Comment: Where do you ever produce an output? I don't see any `print`s.

Comment: I'll make an edit clarifying that point.

Comment: Add `battle_log.append('Thread {name} startet')` at the beginning of your `Thread`.